# numpy size fails on large list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a long list of pandas data frames, according to type, "pandas.core.series.Series". There might be a million entries in this list. 
I created it by splitting a data frame with numpy.array_split.

Each one of the data frames supposedly contains only one number at this moment:

```
In[29]: df1[0:5]
Out[29]: 
[1    12149992.0
Name: 3121916261129, dtype: float64, 2    12149995.0
Name: 3121916261129, dtype: float64, 3    12149997.0
Name: 3121916261129, dtype: float64, 4    12149994.0
Name: 3121916261129, dtype: float64, 5    12149993.0
Name: 3121916261129, dtype: float64]
```

Now when I want to know how large this list is, I use the size function of numpy, which fails after some time:

```
In [31]: np.size(df1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/sw/Dropbox (IQOQI_Vienna)/dataanalysis_results/allan/allanvariance_pandas1khz.py in <module>()
----> 1 np.size(df1)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in size(a, axis)
   2693             return a.size
   2694         except AttributeError:
-> 2695             return asarray(a).size
   2696     else:
   2697         try:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    601         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    602         try:
--> 603             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    604 
    605             if not is_scalar(result):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   2167         try:
   2168             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2169                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2170         except KeyError as e1:
   2171             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3557)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3240)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8564)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8508)()

KeyError: 0
In [32]:
```

Frankly I don't understand this error message. Also, I am looking for a better method to determine the size of this list. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try doing np.size(df1.values) or np.size(df1.to_matrix())

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, that doesn't seem to work. "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'". Same with "to_matrix()"

Comment: I thought df1 was a dataframe, but the error you mentioned in the comment says its a list.

Comment: As far as I understand, it's a list of data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors indicate that NumPy is trying to convert your list to an array but fails. Instead, you could add up the sizes by:

```
sum(series.size for series in df1)
```